# Why does the variable d1 in a function give the error "d1 is not defined" (it was working but now it's not)

Tags: python

'''This is the version of a dice-roll I came up with. I know I am not that smart, and rather slow minded. But I am trying learn and make this code work. The variable d1 is getting the error "d1 is not defined", which stops the roll.'''

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random
from statistics import mean, stdev

def dice():
    count = 0
    d1=([random.randint(1,6) for _ in range(10)])
    count = count + d1  
    d2=([random.randint(1,6) for _ in range(10)])
    count = count + d2

    tot=(d1+d2)
    medi=mean(d1,d2)
    stand=stdev(d1,d2)


print(d1,d2)
print(tot)
print(medi)
print(stand)
```

Comment: `d1` is only defined within the `dice()` function.  If you try to access it inside a different function, or at the main level, it will be undefined.

Comment: Your indentation got all messed up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having this problem because in python a variable inside a function belongs to that function. It can not be accessed outside this function. I would rewrite your code a bit, as I think there is a bit much going on in your function.

```py
import random
def dice_roll():
    d1 = random.randint(1,6)
    d2 = random.randint(1,6)
    return (d1,d2) #returns a tuple of your dice roll
def dice_totals(rolls):
    totals = [num1 + num2 for num1, num2 in rolls]
    return totals #returns a list of the totals of the rolls
rolls = [dice_roll() for i in range(10)]
total = dice_totals(rolls)
print(total)
print(rolls)
#Output:
#[6, 6, 10, 7, 10, 6, 10, 8, 5, 7]
#[(1, 5), (2, 4), (5, 5), (5, 2), (6, 4), (2, 4), (5, 5), (5, 3), (4, 1), (1, 6)]
```

This then gives you a list of tuples containing each dice roll, and a list containing the total of each roll. From there you can run your statistics on the dice rolls.

Its generally good practice to have short precise functions. This makes it easier for you to debug and update.

Comment: You are the Statistician 'jedkea', your contribution was exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you very much. Problem solved

Comment: Glad it helped. If it solved your problems would you mind accepting my answer with the checkmark beside it?